# Join two table using Criteria in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, nhibernate-hql

I have query like this written in hql format:

```
Query qq = session.createQuery(
    "select question from Question question " +
    "join question.information.tags t1 " +
    "join question.information.tags t2 " +
    "where t1.name = 'java' and t2.id = 63"
        );
```

I wrote this query in Criteria format but it trow exception:

```
session.createCriteria(Question.class, "q")
        .createAlias("q.information.tags", "t1")
        .createAlias("q.information.tags", "t2")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("t1.id", "63"))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("t2.name", "java"))
        .list();
```

> Method threw 'org.hibernate.QueryException' exception.: 
>   duplicate association path: information.tags

What is the problem? Any way to write hql in Criteria format?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082981/4808122) a workaround using `SqlRestriction` with `exists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to join the same association twice with Criteria

You can find the related JIRA [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879) that is still open.